# How to filter numbers in a drop down list?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have an HTML table with a numeric variable called `statut`.

The `statut` variable is a drop-down list, it has two values -> `1` and `9`.

The method in typescript seems to be correct

```
  public selectedBrand: any;
  public onChangeStatut(statut: number) {
    this.selectedBrand = statut;
    this.filteredCustomer = this.customerTransferts.filter(
        (item) => item.statut === this.selectedBrand
    );
    console.log(this.filteredCustomer);
  }
```

I think my problem is the HTML, how to make the HTML know that it must filter a number and not a string?

```
<select class="form-select" style="max-width: 100px" [ngModel]="selectedBrand" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatut($event)">
  <option [value]="'1'" >1</option>
  <option [value]="'9'">9</option>
</select>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting `this.selectedBrand` to a number should work.
The `+` will do the trick here.

```
item.statut === +this.selectedBrand
```